# Find amount of numbers in a text file that are greater than a certain number

Tags: python, string, text

So basically for this assignment we were given 2 text files with a list of MPG's from many cars, one file was for MPG in a city and the other is MPG on the highway. I have all the code right except for the statements after the "if" statement. Python keeps saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    GasGuzzlers("carModelData_city", "carModelData_hwy")
 File "<pyshell#2>", line 7, in GasGuzzlers
    num+=1
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

This is my code:

```
def GasGuzzlers(list1, list2):
    num = 0
    num2 = 0
    with open(list1, "r") as list1: 
        for num in list1.readlines(): 
            if (float(num) < 22.0):
                num+=1
    with open(list2, "r") as list2:
        for num2 in list2.readlines(): 
             if (float(num2) < 27.0):
                num2+=1
    print(count1, count2)
```

This is was my prof's instruction:

"Write a function that calculates the number of gas guzzlers among the vehicle models tested – for this program, define a “gas guzzler” as a car that gets EITHER less than 22 mpg city OR less than 27 mpg highway."

Please help! I'm so close to getting it, I've tried to convert the float(num) to a string in many different ways and it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding `num = float(num)` above `if (float(num) < 22.0):` and changing that line to `if (num < 22.0):` (in both for loops).  Your converting the string to a float "locally" inside the if condition, but it's not persisting to the next line where you try to add an int to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 0
```

is overridden by

```
for num in list1.readlines():
```

and

```
num2+=1
```

is overridden by

```
for num2 in list2.readlines():
```

read/readlines will return a string/list. In your case, I guess the variables are accidentally overridden - choose different variable names in the looping constructs and the program should work just fine.

Comment: def GasGuzzlers(list1, list2):
        num = 0
        num2 = 0
        with open(list1, "r") as list1: 
            for num10 in list1: 
                if (float(num10)<22.0): 
                    num+=1

                
        with open(list2, "r") as list2:
            for num20 in list2.readlines(): 
                 if (float(num20) < 27.0):
                    num2+=1
        print(num, num2)

Comment: I changed it to this, but print returned very large numbers and I know it's not right because the files containg the numbers don't even contain that many. It returned "19967 8709"

Comment: print(count1, count2)
I think this should be:     print(num, num2)

Comment: Also, there's a lot of variable overlap - "    with open(list1, "r") as list1: 
" - "as list1" could be "as fd1" (so that you don't lose the original value of list1 that represents the file name)